# Creating links to embed page

Tags: php, hyperlink, embed

I have created an index.php that serves as a template with a content box. I also have home.php, about.php, and contact.php which only contain the content to fill that content box. This is the code I use to embed pages into that content box:

```
<?php 
    if(!$_GET[page]){ 
        include "home.php"; // Page to goto if nothing picked 
    } else { 
        include $_GET[page]."php"; // test.php?page=links would read links.php 
    } 
?>
```

The home page works fine but I am not sure what code to use in the main menu to link to the other pages. I am having a very hard time getting an answer, so I think I may be searching with the wrong terms, which is why I am asking here.

On the main menu for the website, what code do I use in the links so that they get home.php, about.php, or contact.php?

Comment: Do you want to link `/contact.php` instead of `/index.php?page=contact`? Then you are looking for [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Your vulnerable to directory traversal attack, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Path_Traversal also using `$_GET[page]` is deprecated, use `$_GET['page']` instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="index.php?page=about">About</a>

?<key>=<value> in the url.
```

You look up a value in the $_GET-array by using the key.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following test:

```
$page = "test.php?page=links";
$link = explode("=", $page);
echo $link[1].".php"; //gets links.php
```

So, your code should looks like:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET[page])){ 
     $page = $_GET[page];
     $link = explode("=", $page);
     include $link[1].".php"; // test.php?page=links would read links.php 

} else { 
    include "home.php"; // Page to goto if nothing picked 
    } 
?>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$_GET[page]){ 
    include "home.php"; // Page to goto if nothing picked 
} else { 
    include $_GET[page].".php"; // test.php?page=links would read links.php 
}
```

It was just missing the '.' before the 'php'. 
You should use Quotes for arrays though to avoid a Notice (Undefined constant)

Be careful though, you should verify that $_GET['page'] only contains sites you want to make accessible. Otherwise an attacker could just read any file on your server.

```
if(array_key_exists('page', $_GET)) {
    $page = preg_replace('~[^a-z]~', '', $_GET['page']);
    include __DIR__ . '/' . $page . '.php';
} else {
    include __DIR__ . '/home.php';
}
```

Better solution (but you have to manually add all the pages):

```
$page = (array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home');
switch($page) {
    case 'about':
    case 'links':
    case 'whatever':
        include __DIR__ . '/' . $page . '.php';
        break;
    default:
        include __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
}
```